# SQLite3: specifying the starting rowid to begin a SELECT search?

Tags: select, search, sqlite, query-optimization, rowid

Is it possible to specify the starting rowid where a SELECT statement should start searching and continue to search to last rowid?

Background:
 - I am using SQLite3 on embedded system(raspberry pi), so CPU speed is
   an issue. 
 - The database itself is a static set of observations, with a static
   string identifier like: "Axxxx"; "Bxxxx"; "Cxxxx"
 - Since entries are static I know all the "Axxxx"'s will start at rowid=0;
   and for example the "Cxxxx"'s may not start until rowid=(large number
   ? ie. 10 million) 
 - So when search/SELECT a "Cxxxx" entry is it possible to specify the search to
   start at rowid=10 million so as not to waste time searching first 10
   million entries.

Comment: `WHERE ROWID > 10000000`?

Comment: Sounds like you need an index on this string column. If it's a unique value, also consider making it the primary key (possibly of a [WITHOUT ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) table).

Comment: Thanks the rowid > xxxx works ! Newbie embarrassment here ! And actually it improved query processing time from minutes to few seconds when combined with a row lookup table!